# Get top-level category and make it a link

Tags: wordpress, loops, get, parent, categories

Wordpress - Trying to get the top-level parent category name and make it a link

Categories are structured as

Europe > Eastern Europe > Poland

In this instance I wan to get the cat name for Europe and make it a link to the cat page for Europe.

No matter what I try I do not seem to be able to get the top most category. This is being executed in a custom QP Query

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

### [Get only top level categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories#Get_only_top_level_categories)

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0
  );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a><br/>';
}
?>
```

### [Get top level categories / taxonomy](http://wp-snippets.com/get-top-level-categories-taxonomy/)

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'type'          => 'post',
    'orderby'       => 'term_group',
    'hide_empty'    => 0,
    'hierarchical'  => 0,
    'parent'        => 0,
    'taxonomy'      => '..if you are using a taxonomy instead of a category'
);
get_categories( $args ); 
?>
```

Comment: I think this will work, however I am not trying to echo the result. I would like to set the string you are echoing as a variable which I can call some where else...can you help with that?

Comment: @user1447958 *set the string you are echoing as a variable* which string you are referring ?

Comment: how would I set this as a variable:     echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a><br/>';

Comment: if you want to put this whole in variable you can do in this way `$link= '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a><br/>';`

And then `echo $link;` where you want .I hope this is what you want